# Software update never worked in Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s-2, ota-update

Whenever I try
**Settings -> About Phone -> Software Update -> Check for update**
I get the error message "Connection failed"

More Information -

1. I am connected to Internet. and Internet works in my phone.
2. I have configured Samsung account in my mobile.

Comment: How are you connected to the internet?  It needs to be over a data connection, not Wi-Fi.

Comment: Seconded - I've tried over a data connection as well as WiFi. Same error. Hoping for an update for India from the current 2.3.3

Comment: @MatthewRead Yes its over data connection only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Galaxy S2 doesn't support OTA updates...so it's unlikely that you will be able to check for updates from your phone. The same "Connection Failed" error comes to me when I try that in my phone.

Comment: then what are the other ways to update the phone software?

Comment: @emaillenin download Kies for your computer and connect the phone via USB, it should prompt you for updating.

Answer (score 2):

Dial *#8736364# to check for an update.

Comment: same error "Connection failed" when tried using this way